# Using hasOwnProperty() on an array

Tags: javascript, sorting, hasownproperty

Can I use hasOwnProperty() on an array? I have this array of [RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_model) values:

```
colors = [[240,120,120,255], [125,222,111,255], [9,56,237,255], [240,120,120,255], [240,120,120,255], [240,120,120,255]]
```

I'd like to create an object that sorts them in order of their frequency in the array. I'm trying a combination of things.

First I thought to convert the array into an object using:

```
function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
    rv[i] = arr[i];
  }
  //console.log('the array is now this ', rv)
  return rv;
}
```

But that returns something like this:

```
 {0: [240,120,120,255], 1:[125,222,111,255],2:[9,56,237,255], 3:[240,120,120,255], 4:[240,120,120,255], 5:[240,120,120,255]}
```

So I'm wondering if I can call hasOwnProperty on it like this?

```
  function reduceColors(passedArray){
    var empty = {}
    return passedArray.filter(function(item){
      return empty.hasOwnProperty(item["value"])
    })
  }
```

Comment: Is expected result that elements having most elements in common in any order themselves with other sub-arrays, or exact sequence match? That is,  expected result would be `[240,120,120,255],[240,120,120,255],[240,120,120,255],[240,120,120,255]` followed by either `[125,222,111,255],[9,56,237,255]` or `[9,56,237,255], [125,222,111,255]` ?

Comment: First things first; in JS `[240,120,120,255] === [240,120,120,255] // <- false`

Comment: exact sequence match, because these are [r,g,b,a] colors values.

Comment: "sorts them in order of their frequency" ... tantalizing endeavor and something computers can be great at!  algorithms to the rescue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hashing for this.
With hashing you can group the arrays that have the same values in the same orders and you can count their frequency.

Here is an example:

```js
var colors = [[240,120,120,255], [125,222,111,255], [9,56,237,255], [240,120,120,255], [240,120,120,255], [240,120,120,255]];


var hashed = [];

colors.forEach(function(arr){
    var id = hash(arr);
    var contains = hashed.find(v => v.id == id);
    if(contains){
        contains.count++;
    }else{
        hashed.push({id:id, color:arr, count:1});
    }
});

hashed.sort(function(a,b){return b.count - a.count;})

console.log(hashed);

function hash(arr){
  var hash = "#";
  arr.forEach(function(v){
     hash+=v.toString(16);
  });
  return hash;
}
```

In this example, I'm creating the hash by converting the RGBA values to hexadecimal numbers, but a better solution will be to store them like that (in hexadecimal), so you will have a one-dimensional array instead of a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Wow! This example is so clear and wonderful. Thank you for explaining it and even with working code. That makes it really easy to understand. Thank you

Comment: except this totally does not answer the question of if you can use hasOwnProperty on an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop, `Array.prototype.filter()`, `Array.prototype.every()`, and the strict equality operator to check if each array within `colors` contains each element of a sibling array within `colors` at same index; concatenate each matched sibling array to an output array

```js
colors = [
  [240, 120, 120, 255],
  [125, 222, 111, 255],
  [9, 56, 237, 255],
  [240, 120, 120, 255],
  [240, 120, 120, 255],
  [240, 120, 120, 255]
]
var res = [];

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  if (res.length < colors.length) {
    [...res] = [...res,
      ...colors.filter(function(el) {
        return el.every(function(elem, index) {
          return elem === colors[i][index]
        })
      })
    ]
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

console.log(res);
```